# Adding cells to change in solver

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range from A1 to J1 that I would like to change using solver to optimize a certain value. Usually, I do the following:

```
SolverOK ByChange:=Range("A1:J1")
```

However, my program randomly fills in some cells in the range A1:J1 with fixed numbers that must remain there. How do I only add the empty cells to the SolverOk ByChange:= argument?

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1 J1
0      1        1           0
```

For example I might have the above setup and I would only want to add cells B1, D1, E1, G1, H1, and I1 to the solver change cells argument.

I tried looping through the empty cells and adding them to solver but that didn't work because only the last blank cell would be added and not the other ones. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture any truly blank cells in a range (using `SpecialCells(xlBlanks)`) then feed this address into the Solver VBA (`ByChange:=rng1.Address`), ie sample code below which runs if there are blank cells

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:J1").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        SolverOk SetCell:="$B$2", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=rng1.Address, Engine:= _
                 1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share a similar problem that I solved using the above solution.  I wanted to create a macro to temporarily "lock" a cell (removing it from the list of cells to change) if I had a value I wanted to be fixed for that specific run.  There may be a more elegant way of doing it, but by using this code I was able to press a button to put a character in the cell two over from the one I wished to lock (added benefit of showing that the cell is locked) and have that adjust the list of cells to change without having to open the solver window.

```
Sub Lock1B()
Dim rng1 As Range
Range("X7") = "#"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Range("X7:X15").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        SolverOk ByChange:=rng1.Offset(0, 2).Address
    End If
```